# Why is this PostgreSQL query with LIMIT so slow?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, entity-framework-core, limit

I have a .NET WebApi with two entities (please forgive the silly names, it's just an example):

```
public class Father
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int? ChildAId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildBId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildCId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildDId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildEId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildFId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildGId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildHId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildIId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildJId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildKId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildLId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildMId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildNId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildOId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildPId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildQId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildRId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildSId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildTId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildUId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildVId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildWId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildXId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildYId { get; set; }
    public int? ChildZId { get; set; }
    public int? Child0Id { get; set; }
    public int? Child1Id { get; set; }
    public int? Child2Id { get; set; }
    public int? Child3Id { get; set; }
    public int? Child4Id { get; set; }
    public int? Child5Id { get; set; }
    public int? Child6Id { get; set; }
    public int? Child7Id { get; set; }
    public int? Child8Id { get; set; }
    public int? Child9Id { get; set; }

    public Child? ChildA { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildB { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildC { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildD { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildE { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildF { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildG { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildH { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildI { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildJ { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildK { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildL { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildM { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildN { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildO { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildP { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildQ { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildR { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildS { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildT { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildU { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildV { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildW { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildX { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildY { get; set; }
    public Child? ChildZ { get; set; }
    public Child? Child0 { get; set; }
    public Child? Child1 { get; set; }
    public Child? Child2 { get; set; }
    public Child? Child3 { get; set; }
    public Child? Child4 { get; set; }
    public Child? Child5 { get; set; }
    public Child? Child6 { get; set; }
    public Child? Child7 { get; set; }
    public Child? Child8 { get; set; }
    public Child? Child9 { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I have inserted 100.000 fathers with their children from A to Z populated. Now I'm trying to recover them from the database using EF Core (but PgAdmin gives the same results).

20 FATHERS WITH LIMIT/OFFSET

```
SELECT f."Id", f."Child0Id", f."Child1Id", f."Child2Id", f."Child3Id", f."Child4Id", f."Child5Id", f."Child6Id", f."Child7Id", f."Child8Id", f."Child9Id", f."ChildAId", f."ChildBId", f."ChildCId", f."ChildDId", f."ChildEId", f."ChildFId", f."ChildGId", f."ChildHId", f."ChildIId", f."ChildJId", f."ChildKId", f."ChildLId", f."ChildMId", f."ChildNId", f."ChildOId", f."ChildPId", f."ChildQId", f."ChildRId", f."ChildSId", f."ChildTId", f."ChildUId", f."ChildVId", f."ChildWId", f."ChildXId", f."ChildYId", f."ChildZId", f."Name"
FROM "Father" AS f
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 98000
```

Query completes in 130ms

20 FATHERS WITH ALL THEIR CHILDREN AND LIMIT/OFFSET

```
  SELECT t."Id", t."Child0Id", t."Child1Id", t."Child2Id", t."Child3Id", t."Child4Id", t."Child5Id", t."Child6Id", t."Child7Id", t."Child8Id", t."Child9Id", t."ChildAId", t."ChildBId", t."ChildCId", t."ChildDId", t."ChildEId", t."ChildFId", t."ChildGId", t."ChildHId", t."ChildIId", t."ChildJId", t."ChildKId", t."ChildLId", t."ChildMId", t."ChildNId", t."ChildOId", t."ChildPId", t."ChildQId", t."ChildRId", t."ChildSId", t."ChildTId", t."ChildUId", t."ChildVId", t."ChildWId", t."ChildXId", t."ChildYId", t."ChildZId", t."Name", c."Id", c."Description", c."Name", c0."Id", c0."Description", c0."Name", c1."Id", c1."Description", c1."Name", c2."Id", c2."Description", c2."Name", c3."Id", c3."Description", c3."Name", c4."Id", c4."Description", c4."Name", c5."Id", c5."Description", c5."Name", c6."Id", c6."Description", c6."Name", c7."Id", c7."Description", c7."Name", c8."Id", c8."Description", c8."Name", c9."Id", c9."Description", c9."Name", c10."Id", c10."Description", c10."Name", c11."Id", c11."Description", c11."Name", c12."Id", c12."Description", c12."Name", c13."Id", c13."Description", c13."Name", c14."Id", c14."Description", c14."Name", c15."Id", c15."Description", c15."Name", c16."Id", c16."Description", c16."Name", c17."Id", c17."Description", c17."Name", c18."Id", c18."Description", c18."Name", c19."Id", c19."Description", c19."Name", c20."Id", c20."Description", c20."Name", c21."Id", c21."Description", c21."Name", c22."Id", c22."Description", c22."Name", c23."Id", c23."Description", c23."Name", c24."Id", c24."Description", c24."Name", c25."Id", c25."Description", c25."Name", c26."Id", c26."Description", c26."Name", c27."Id", c27."Description", c27."Name", c28."Id", c28."Description", c28."Name", c29."Id", c29."Description", c29."Name", c30."Id", c30."Description", c30."Name", c31."Id", c31."Description", c31."Name", c32."Id", c32."Description", c32."Name", c33."Id", c33."Description", c33."Name", c34."Id", c34."Description", c34."Name"
  FROM (
      SELECT f."Id", f."Child0Id", f."Child1Id", f."Child2Id", f."Child3Id", f."Child4Id", f."Child5Id", f."Child6Id", f."Child7Id", f."Child8Id", f."Child9Id", f."ChildAId", f."ChildBId", f."ChildCId", f."ChildDId", f."ChildEId", f."ChildFId", f."ChildGId", f."ChildHId", f."ChildIId", f."ChildJId", f."ChildKId", f."ChildLId", f."ChildMId", f."ChildNId", f."ChildOId", f."ChildPId", f."ChildQId", f."ChildRId", f."ChildSId", f."ChildTId", f."ChildUId", f."ChildVId", f."ChildWId", f."ChildXId", f."ChildYId", f."ChildZId", f."Name"
      FROM "Father" AS f
      LIMIT 20 OFFSET 98000
  ) AS t
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c ON t."ChildAId" = c."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c0 ON t."ChildBId" = c0."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c1 ON t."ChildCId" = c1."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c2 ON t."ChildDId" = c2."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c3 ON t."ChildEId" = c3."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c4 ON t."ChildFId" = c4."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c5 ON t."ChildGId" = c5."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c6 ON t."ChildHId" = c6."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c7 ON t."ChildIId" = c7."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c8 ON t."ChildJId" = c8."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c9 ON t."ChildKId" = c9."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c10 ON t."ChildLId" = c10."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c11 ON t."ChildMId" = c11."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c12 ON t."ChildNId" = c12."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c13 ON t."ChildOId" = c13."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c14 ON t."ChildPId" = c14."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c15 ON t."ChildQId" = c15."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c16 ON t."ChildRId" = c16."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c17 ON t."ChildSId" = c17."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c18 ON t."ChildTId" = c18."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c19 ON t."ChildUId" = c19."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c20 ON t."ChildVId" = c20."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c21 ON t."ChildWId" = c21."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c22 ON t."ChildXId" = c22."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c23 ON t."ChildYId" = c23."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c24 ON t."ChildZId" = c24."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c25 ON t."Child0Id" = c25."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c26 ON t."Child1Id" = c26."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c27 ON t."Child2Id" = c27."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c28 ON t."Child3Id" = c28."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c29 ON t."Child4Id" = c29."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c30 ON t."Child5Id" = c30."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c31 ON t."Child6Id" = c31."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c32 ON t."Child7Id" = c32."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c33 ON t."Child8Id" = c33."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c34 ON t."Child9Id" = c34."Id"
```

Query completes in 300ms

SINGLE FATHER BY ID (WITH LIMIT SET BY SINGLEORDEFAULT)

```
SELECT f."Id", f."Child0Id", f."Child1Id", f."Child2Id", f."Child3Id", f."Child4Id", f."Child5Id", f."Child6Id", f."Child7Id", f."Child8Id", f."Child9Id", f."ChildAId", f."ChildBId", f."ChildCId", f."ChildDId", f."ChildEId", f."ChildFId", f."ChildGId", f."ChildHId", f."ChildIId", f."ChildJId", f."ChildKId", f."ChildLId", f."ChildMId", f."ChildNId", f."ChildOId", f."ChildPId", f."ChildQId", f."ChildRId", f."ChildSId", f."ChildTId", f."ChildUId", f."ChildVId", f."ChildWId", f."ChildXId", f."ChildYId", f."ChildZId", f."Name"
      FROM "Father" AS f
      WHERE f."Id" = 1
      LIMIT 2
```

Query completes in 115ms

NOW COMES THE PROBLEM: SINGLE FATHER WITH ALL CHILDREN BY ID (WITH LIMIT SET BY SINGLEORDEFAULT)

```
  SELECT f."Id", f."Child0Id", f."Child1Id", f."Child2Id", f."Child3Id", f."Child4Id", f."Child5Id", f."Child6Id", f."Child7Id", f."Child8Id", f."Child9Id", f."ChildAId", f."ChildBId", f."ChildCId", f."ChildDId", f."ChildEId", f."ChildFId", f."ChildGId", f."ChildHId", f."ChildIId", f."ChildJId", f."ChildKId", f."ChildLId", f."ChildMId", f."ChildNId", f."ChildOId", f."ChildPId", f."ChildQId", f."ChildRId", f."ChildSId", f."ChildTId", f."ChildUId", f."ChildVId", f."ChildWId", f."ChildXId", f."ChildYId", f."ChildZId", f."Name", c."Id", c."Description", c."Name", c0."Id", c0."Description", c0."Name", c1."Id", c1."Description", c1."Name", c2."Id", c2."Description", c2."Name", c3."Id", c3."Description", c3."Name", c4."Id", c4."Description", c4."Name", c5."Id", c5."Description", c5."Name", c6."Id", c6."Description", c6."Name", c7."Id", c7."Description", c7."Name", c8."Id", c8."Description", c8."Name", c9."Id", c9."Description", c9."Name", c10."Id", c10."Description", c10."Name", c11."Id", c11."Description", c11."Name", c12."Id", c12."Description", c12."Name", c13."Id", c13."Description", c13."Name", c14."Id", c14."Description", c14."Name", c15."Id", c15."Description", c15."Name", c16."Id", c16."Description", c16."Name", c17."Id", c17."Description", c17."Name", c18."Id", c18."Description", c18."Name", c19."Id", c19."Description", c19."Name", c20."Id", c20."Description", c20."Name", c21."Id", c21."Description", c21."Name", c22."Id", c22."Description", c22."Name", c23."Id", c23."Description", c23."Name", c24."Id", c24."Description", c24."Name", c25."Id", c25."Description", c25."Name", c26."Id", c26."Description", c26."Name", c27."Id", c27."Description", c27."Name", c28."Id", c28."Description", c28."Name", c29."Id", c29."Description", c29."Name", c30."Id", c30."Description", c30."Name", c31."Id", c31."Description", c31."Name", c32."Id", c32."Description", c32."Name", c33."Id", c33."Description", c33."Name", c34."Id", c34."Description", c34."Name"
  FROM "Father" AS f
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c ON f."ChildAId" = c."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c0 ON f."ChildBId" = c0."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c1 ON f."ChildCId" = c1."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c2 ON f."ChildDId" = c2."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c3 ON f."ChildEId" = c3."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c4 ON f."ChildFId" = c4."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c5 ON f."ChildGId" = c5."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c6 ON f."ChildHId" = c6."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c7 ON f."ChildIId" = c7."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c8 ON f."ChildJId" = c8."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c9 ON f."ChildKId" = c9."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c10 ON f."ChildLId" = c10."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c11 ON f."ChildMId" = c11."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c12 ON f."ChildNId" = c12."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c13 ON f."ChildOId" = c13."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c14 ON f."ChildPId" = c14."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c15 ON f."ChildQId" = c15."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c16 ON f."ChildRId" = c16."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c17 ON f."ChildSId" = c17."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c18 ON f."ChildTId" = c18."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c19 ON f."ChildUId" = c19."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c20 ON f."ChildVId" = c20."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c21 ON f."ChildWId" = c21."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c22 ON f."ChildXId" = c22."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c23 ON f."ChildYId" = c23."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c24 ON f."ChildZId" = c24."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c25 ON f."Child0Id" = c25."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c26 ON f."Child1Id" = c26."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c27 ON f."Child2Id" = c27."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c28 ON f."Child3Id" = c28."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c29 ON f."Child4Id" = c29."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c30 ON f."Child5Id" = c30."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c31 ON f."Child6Id" = c31."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c32 ON f."Child7Id" = c32."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c33 ON f."Child8Id" = c33."Id"
  LEFT JOIN "Child" AS c34 ON f."Child9Id" = c34."Id"
  WHERE f."Id" = 1
  LIMIT 2
```

Query completes in MORE THAN TWO SECONDS! 2300ms

Can someone explain me why and how to optimize this query? I have indexes on all PKs and FKs.

Comment: What does the execution plan for the query tell you about this?

Comment: It does all the nested loop left joins, and then limits. I don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: The execution probably bypass index if it evaluates that it'll be worthless...
Without more data it's hard to make sure.

On a related note : What's the point of your limit here ? Id is not unique ?
Could you use an association table here instead of so many Child columns ?

Comment: Limit is automatically set by Entity Framework when you do a SingleOrDefaults() as it needs to check if there are duplicates. I can't use an association table by design. The example is silly but it has a meaning in the real application.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no `ORDER BY` in the slow query?

Comment: Yes, it's the query I wrote in the question

Comment: You need to rethink your design. Unpivot the `ChildId` into separate rows in a separate table, and retrieve all the data using a single join, with a long skinny shape (a few columns, lots of rows) rather than a wide shallow shape (many columns, few rows).

Comment: The problem is the query and the design, not LIMIT. You're performing 34 JOINs on fields that may not be covered by an index. Specifying a relation in a DbContext doesn't create an index on the underlying table.

Comment: I do not see any LINQ query in the question. What you are trying to optimize?

Comment: Wrong data model, something your database can't fix for you. A child should have a column id_father, not the other way around. That would give you a query with just one LEFT JOIN for all children, instead of one left join for each child.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I can't do that as data model was dictated from outside. This is just a silly example, every child has a precise role for father and can't have a role column. By the way this doesn't explain why the list is fast, and the single record is so slow.

Comment: If you can't change the design ,(1) you may try using a query that selects child fields with subquery instead of joining so many tables, or (2) You might try to force the filtering before joining (though i doubt it would improve dramatically stuff) Or (3) selecting only the father. Then selecting childs in a second query and mixing it in code. (Though none may be applicable depending on your context)

Comment: I can't change the data model, unfortunately. There's a reason why it is designed like that.

Comment: Sure, that's why i suggested 3 changes in the way the query are made ^^
Unless you can't change that either ?

Comment: In that case, your performance problem is not big enough and you don't have to do anything. Your data model doesn't work for a relational database, like PostgreSQL. When each child has a specific role, you should make that part of the child. Not the father. And you can always change the data model. You could even keep the current flawed model in your database, implemented as views that use the underlying improved data model.

Comment: Sorry @FrankHeikens, you seem to miss the point that my "flawed" design has no performance issues when selecting a list, and breaks only with the LIMIT clause. I can't change the data model as it's a requirement by other systems that access that table.

Comment: @JulienB., can you please elaborate option 1?

Comment: @Alessandro: I doubt it would make things better but basically you could try sthing like : with ids as (select child1id, child2Id... from father where id = ), child1 as (select * from .. where id = ids.child1id) ... SELECT (select field1 from child1) as f1c1, (select field2 from child1) f2c1. But i really don't think it will make things any better ^^